# Android Tv Operator Tier

Tags: android, android-tv, android-launcher

We would like to develop a custom launcher for a custom android certificated tv box. I read on stackoverflow that we need to enter to Android Tv "Operator Tier" program to qualified as operator. Can somebody tell me how to do that, or where can I apply for this program? Unfortunately We can't find any information about this.

Comment: @geriie, did you find contact point for the operator tier program ? any help would be greatly appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Google through the form here: https://www.android.com/gms/contact/